# Get actual width rather than auto using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

How can I determine the explicit width of a HTML element that has width auto using PHP?

JQuery has the ability to do this if `width:auto;` is used it can compute the actual [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

> Get the current computed width for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements.

JQuery probably does this with the help of the browser as it is client side.

How can I achieve this using PHP? I have the HTML as a string.

### Update

All CSS is inline, if the width is auto, the only thing left to determine the width of the element is its immediate parent and/or its contents.

Comment: this cannot be done with just php. its a javascript thing, but you could count how many chars and multiply by 5, 5 being the pixel width.

Comment: @Lawrence - the width is a JQuery function but it doesn't mean it can not be done with PHP. I am sure it somehow can be computed using the contents of the element. I don't know how but it seems possible.

Comment: @Abs: It cannot be done with PHP.

Comment: @Abs It would require recursively totaling up all the margins and paddings of all nested elements until you arrived at one with a fixed pixel width, _if_ you arrived at a fixed one. Also, the margins and paddings and font sizes would also not all be fixed so you'd have to do the same for those to account for them.  This is so far from trivial that it took Microsoft until IE8 to get it right!

Comment: If a `<div>` is created in the woods and there's no browser to render it, does it have a width?

Comment: @Michael - lol that is a good one! Well, I am going to have to load the HTML in an iframe then get its width using some JS. A little long winded and annoying but it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this would be possible in PHP is if you have *both* the HTML and the complete CSS as strings **AND** the width of the element is defined in absolute pixels or the width of its container (or the parent's container, etc) is defined in absolute pixels.  If all these conditions were true, it would still be extremely difficult to figure out. Basically you'd have to code a rendering engine in PHP.

If you were really lucky, the element you needed would have an inline `style="width:px"` and you could parse for that attribute.

This is possible in Javascript because the browser knows its own size.  Under most circumstances, the HTML in a string doesn't have a size until rendered in a browser.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible. PHP does not know how the HTML/CSS will be rendered (if rendered at all).